# CNN alternates between good performance and chance

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a binary classification problem I am trying to solve with a CNN written in Keras. The input are very sparse `200X125X2` tensors (can be though of as two images stacked together), and its nonzero elements are only ones (representing neuron spike trains). The input is generated using a data generator that I have built, so the model is trained using the `fit_generator` function.

I have tried various architectures, and some show a decent performance (~88%), but the thing is that sometimes when I train new models, they don't seem to work at all, **giving a chance (50%) result every epoch**. The weird thing is that **it happens sometimes to the same architectures that worked well before**. I am running the code on Google Colab (GPU) with TensorFlow 2.0. I have check multiple times that I haven't changed anything in the code. I know that random initialization of the weights and biases may cause slight changes in the performance, but it looks like something else.

Any ideas will be very helpful. Thanks!

Here is the relevant code for one of the models that had this problem (I am using unusual kernels, I know):

```
# General settings

x_max = 10 
x_size, t_size, N_features = parameters(x_max)
batch_size = 64
N_epochs = 10
N_final = 10*N_features                                    
N_final = int(N_final - N_final%(batch_size))
N_val = 100*batch_size
N_test = N_final/5

# Setting up the architecture of the network and compiling

model = Sequential()
model.add(SeparableConv2D(50, (50,30), data_format='channels_first', input_shape=(2,x_size, t_size)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(SeparableConv2D(100, (10,6), data_format='channels_first', input_shape=(2,x_size, t_size)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fitiing the model on generated data

filepath="......hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

start = time.time()
fit_history = model_delta.fit_generator(generator = data_generator(batch_size,x_max,'delta','_',100),
                    steps_per_epoch = N_final//batch_size,
                    validation_data = data_generator(batch_size,x_max,'delta','_',100),
                    validation_steps = N_val//batch_size,
                    callbacks = [checkpoint],
                    epochs = N_epochs)
end = time.time()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most suspicious thing I see is a 'relu' near the end of the model. Depending on the initialization and on the learning rate, ReLUs can be unlucky and fall into an all-zeros case. When this happens, they completely stop gradients and don't train anymore.

By the looks of your problem (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't), it seems very plausible that it's the relu.

So, the first suggesion (this always solves it) is to add a batch normalization before the activation:

```
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

Hint, if you are going to use it with the 4D tensors before the flatten, remember to use the channels dimension: `BatchNormalization(1)`.

Comment: :) -- If you conclude this solved your question, please mark it as answered.